# Let $U$ be a simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$, let $w\in U$. If $f,g\in Aut(U)$ such that $f(w)=g(w)$ and $f'(w)=g'(w)$, show f=g.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I do not even know how to approach this problem when $U=D(0,1)$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riemann mapping theorem?

Comment: I know the statement for proper simply connected domain on P.224 in Stein's complex analysis.  That says uniqueness of $F(z_0)=0$ and $F'(z_0)>0$. For disc, after a rotation, we can make $f'(w)=g'(w)>0$. Hence, it is solved for disc, right? But what about $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: By the Riemann mapping theorem, $U$ is equivalent to either the upper half plane or the whole plane. In both cases, the automorphism group is well-known. Can you derive the result that way?

Comment: Another way to do this is to show the set where $f=g$ on $U$ is both open and closed. Closed is easy, but open takes a bit of work.